# NoMethodError - undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (error point to select helper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying pass the params edited by user when update model failure.
My app render action edit with `format.html { render :edit_company}` and this results:

**undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass**

The error point to my selects and i don't now why.

In Action edit_company i set the state and city of current company, and pass a list of avaiable states and cities to update model.

```
  def edit_company
    states = State.all
    @state_company = @professional_company.professional_company_address.city.state.id
    @city_company = @professional_company.professional_company_address.city.id
    state = State.find(@state_company)
    @list_cities = state.cities.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    @list_states = states.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }.insert(0, 'Selecione o estado')
  end
```

In my view i have  two helpers

```
<%= select(:state, @state_company, @list_states, {:selected => @state_company}, {class:"form-control m-input m-input--square", id:"stateSelect" })%>  
<%= ff.select(:city_id, @list_cities , {selected:@city_company}, {class:"form-control m-input m-input--square", id:"city_id"}) %>
```

The complete error stack is:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass:
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb:36:in `grouped_choices?'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb:20:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:163:in `select'
  app/views/professional/companies/_form.html.erb:195:in `block in _app_views_professional_companies__form_html_erb__1642623332971831228_47080343822700'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:203:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:758:in `form_with'
  app/views/professional/companies/_form.html.erb:45:in `_app_views_professional_companies__form_html_erb__1642623332971831228_47080343822700'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:342:in `block in render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:331:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  app/views/professional/companies/edit_company.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_professional_companies_edit_company_html_erb___4525412059839984133_69861543274900'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/leonardo/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  searchkick (2.3.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:214:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  app/controllers/professional/companies_controller.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:201:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/professional/companies_controller.rb:128:in `update'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
  searchkick (2.3.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
  actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
  puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
  puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Please post the complete error stack trace here.

Comment: Now is in the question

Comment: Now it would be great to see `app/views/professional/companies/_form.html.erb:195` LOC.

Comment: The problem occurs only when i use the select helpers mentioned in the question

Comment: They are in _form.html.erb at line 195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem lies in the fact that in the update failure state you said you're doing this:

```
format.html { render :edit_company}
```

However, that will just render the `edit_company` HTML template - it won't run the `edit_company` action as well (where all of your select lookup arrays are initialized). That's why they are nil when the template is rendered.

Instead, you should move common logic like the select lookups to another method, let's say you call it `load_cities_and_states`, and then you can either call it directly from both `edit_company` and `update`, or even better, you could use a before_action reference at the top of your controller:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_cities_and_states, only: [:edit_company, :update]
end
```

The above will make sure `load_cities_and_states` is run before `edit_company` and `update`.

N.B. I notice that your current code references a `@professional_company` variable that isn't defined in `edit_company`, so I imagine that must be something that is also being initialized in a `before_action` somewhere too, or is part of your user authorization perhaps. Make sure that `load_cities_and_states` happens after that so that `@professional_company` exists, or else you'll have another `undefined method on NilClass` error.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

empty? is a ruby method on Array so it can't be called on a nil object.

Somewhere your code is expecting an array and is receiving nil so trying to call empty? on it raises the error.

Also don't use map, which is a ruby method, like you're doing in your controller as that will break out of SQL and drop to ruby.

Instead use [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) which will keep the calls in SQL (AREL) format.

Bad

```
@list_cities = state.cities.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
```

Better

```
@list_cities = state.cities.pluck(:name, :id)
```

Also what you're doing with [insert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) on @list_states instance variable is IMO bad.

If you need to insert another value, you should do it in a helper method. Preferably via returning a new object not mutating the current one. This will allow you to reuse @list_states elsewhere in your code.

I think this is where your nil is coming in too BTW as you're inserting at index 0 a string instead of an array of id and name.

wrong

```
insert(0, 'Selecione o estado')
```

probably correct

```
insert(0, [0, 'Selecione o estado'])
```